Disable formatting in quotes VS Code
I have mics language php file (PHP, HTML, CSS, JS). And I have Intelephense extension. And I have a code like that
<div class="sgmt" data-view="<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'view'); if ($terms != null) : ?><?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?><?php echo $term->term_id; ?>,<?php endforeach; endif; ?>"></div>

When I'm trying to format my code, every php function moving to new line. It's possible to disable formatting in quotes?
I don't need to turn off formatting. I jus want to exclude some code from formatting, or code in quotes
